# Android App build with Monaca IDE and cordova phonegap-facebook-plugin

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, monaca

I am developing Android App with Monaca IDE and trying to use cordova phonegap-facebook-plugin to implement Facebook Login.

The issue is even I follow the instruction in [this thread](http://quia.cf/orange/pooxy4/nph-poxy.pl/es/20/http/stackoverflow.com/questions/26548555/cordova-phonegap-facebook-plugin-android-facebookconnectplugin-is-not-defined)

I have put the correct key (since it says if I giving wrong password it will always give u same bad key) in Facebook App setting.

It still throw "**ReferenceError: facebookConnectPlugin is not defined**"
When I called facebookConnectPlugin.login function.

I have done lots research but still getting same error.

Can anyone who successful integrate this plugin in to Monaca IDE with android app give me some advise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I received an official response from Monaca that this plugin is not supported. At first they gave a canned answer (generic instructions on importing a custom plugin). I then asked for them to try to import the plugin and make it work on their own, and they couldn't. Sigh.

Comment: That's pretty sad since native facebook integration is very important in user experience :(......I have sent the customer support also and got canned answer too, sigh.

Answer (score 2):

Monaca already provides a sample application that can be used for facebook login, have you tried to use it? Here you can find the documentation:

http://docs.monaca.mobi/cur/en/sampleapp/samples/facebook

Comment: Thanks Andi, yes I have tried this and it works as in-app browser, but what I am trying to is to integrate the native facebook login dialog not browser one :), thanks for reply.

Comment: sorry but I never tried to import that plugin, I'll take a look and, in case, inform you ;)

Answer (score 0):

Hi try to add this code !

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
        function onDeviceReady(){
            window.facebookConnectPlugin.login(["email"], function(response) 
            {
                alert("facebookConnectPlugin.login");

                if (response.authResponse) 
                {
                    alert('User is loggedd in');
                    //login success
                } else  {
                    alert('User is not logged in');
                }
        });
}
```

Try to build the app (APK) not in debugger mode (web or debugger)